# How to listen to a daemon output?

Tags: services, daemon, output

I have a daemon that prints some information on to the terminal. I can see these informations by typing: `systemctl status bot.service`, this is working well, but this command doesn't listen to the new output, so if I want to see the new output, generated, then I need to retype the command.

Is there a way to always listen to the daemon and let the output display in the terminal without retype the command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways. You need elevated powers for both (eg. use `sudo`, or be a member of the `systemd-journal` group).

1. Use `journalctl`:

   ```
   journalctl -fu bot
   ```
2. Find the log the output goes to and `tail -f` it. Very likely it's `/var/log/syslog`. Then do:

   ```
   tail -f /var/log/syslog
   ```

   There will be other entries intermixed though.